# How do I add custom objects to Firestore using standard classes?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firebase appp I have a few classes like this:

```
class User (name: String, address: String){

    fun doesSomething(){}

}
```

which I want to add to Firestore like this:

```
val user = User("Test User", "Fakestreet 123")

db.collection("users").document("test user").set(user)
```

The problem is, that I can only use data classes, according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#kotlin+ktx_3). But in my case, my classes contain functions too. I only want to add the properties to my firestore database, of course (So in my example, name and address).

What would be the preferred way to accomplish this? 
I'm new to Kotlin and Android Studio, sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not suggesting that you can only use a data class.  That's just the most common way in Kotlin.

Firestore will not attempt to serialize arbitrary methods on a class.  In order for a property to be considered, it has to have a JavaBeans compatible name or declaration.  That means it's going to look for methods that look like getters and setters. For example, accessors named `getName()` and `setName()` will signal Firestore to take the value provided by `getName()` and assign it to a field called "name".  Your function "doesSomething" will not be serialized.  With Kotlin, properties are automatically converted to getters and setters with JavaBeans compatible names.

I would encourage you to, however, use a data class anyway, and separate your raw data from the methods that work on that data.  It's just better software engineering.